# Fetch as Google not showing Waypoints.js on scroll animation SEO

Tags: jquery, seo, frontend, google-search-console, jquery-waypoints

So #1 I'm sorry if this is not entirely programming, but I feel that it is, because I'm using programming to drive uniqueness to my webpage, but Google doesn't see it.  So it's a webmasters and a programming problem.

So I noticed that my main content underneath 4 reasons to choose LED Habitats did not show up in Fetch as Google as well as a few other sections. The site being brand new, so I'm not sure how this will be indexed.   What happens is, as the user scrolls the content is brought in using Waypoints and Animate.css  which offers an engaging yet simple user experience.  I'm just afraid that If the content doesn't show up in "Fetch as Google" in webmaster tools that this content will never be found / indexed by Google.

There are thousands of sites that use this library, I'm just curious what I'm doing wrong.. or what I can do.

Is there a way for me to keep the simple animations but keep Google Happy at the same time?

I took a screen shot of "Fetch as Google" and you can see blatant missing sections which are the sections animated by the waypoints library.  This being said, is there a way I can keep this library / animation yet have google find it..

Thanks for listening!
[image]

Comment: Questions about how google behaves are definitely not on topic.

Comment: Yes but my question is how to technically correct the problem.   The page does not render the content to google.   It's technically a problem.  Whether an on load type solution or what.  Asking this question in webmaster stack.  No one can solve the problem the only thing they can tell me is it is one.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to Google is to show him content, this content should not be loaded by JS, try to disable the JS from your browser and reload the page, if you see content you are ok, otherwise you should change the way you get the content.

Most of the animations are done using JS so Google won't see them specially in Fetch as Google.

Try the to disable the JS, if there is a content then you are OK.

Comment: I disabled js and all content showed.   Well I guess this question is no longer technical and if this is acceptable.

Comment: Great, so Google now is very happy with your website.

When using Fetch as Google, you use it to see the redirects and if google can access your pages.